# multiple class values in css

Tags: css

My code is like this:

```
<div class="multiplicity one">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="multiplicity two">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="multiplicity three">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my every multiplicity class,I have given three distinct background image. I want to stop background repeat for every three class(multiplicity one,multiplicity two, multiplicity three ) and write the css code like

```
.multiplicity {
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

Is this syntax incorrect??
It does not work. I have tested in Firefox latest version.

Comment: It should work fine if you have image in .multiplicity class. It will be nice if you could post more css or a fiddle. Check this fiddle jsfiddle.net/7wewkysj/2

Comment: I have got it , I wrote background whether it would be background-image. Thank you so much :)  @Richa

Comment: thanks again for the jsfiddle link. I didn't know about it. @Richa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo for you

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7wewkysj/4/)**

```
.multiplicity {
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.one {
    background-image:url(http://i57.tinypic.com/b4erh2.jpg);
}
.two {
    background-image:url(http://i59.tinypic.com/2lkfhuw.jpg);
}
.three {
    background-image:url(http://i57.tinypic.com/2lkflhd.jpg);
}
```

And a demo for **repeat too**

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7wewkysj/5/)**

```
.multiplicity {
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.one {
    background-image:url(http://i57.tinypic.com/b4erh2.jpg);
}
.two {
    background-image:url(http://i59.tinypic.com/2lkfhuw.jpg);
}
.three {
    background-image:url(http://i57.tinypic.com/2lkflhd.jpg);
}
```

Comment: The demo works but what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The background image was being reaped for multiplicity two, multiplicity three class. I have got it , I wrote background whether it would be background-image. Thank you so much @Richa